# Building a Vala Gnome3 extension (indicator-diskman) project on 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell-extension, vala

I would like to build the Gnome3 extension `indicator-diskman` on Ubuntu 18.04, but I have problems doing that. This is what I've tried doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/teejee2008/diskman.git indicator-diskman_git
cd indicator-diskman_git/
```

Here, there are several scripts, and a makefile. It seems these are dependencies for running the scripts:

```
sudo apt install bzr-builddeb
sudo apt install valac
```

With that, running the scripts results with:

```
$ ./build-source.sh 
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/path/to/indicator-diskman_git/".
Failed

$ ./build-deb-for-dist.sh bionic amd64
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/path/to/indicator-diskman_git/".
Failed
./build-deb-for-dist.sh: line 37: cd: ../builds: No such file or directory
sudo: pbuilder: command not found
Failed
```

... which does make sense, as this is a git repo, not a bzr one.

So I read `build.sh`, and it basically calls `make`, so I tried `make`:

```
$ make
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/indicator-diskman_git/src'
#build binaries
valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="indicator-diskman"' --Xcc="-lm" -X -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/indicator-diskman/libs  --thread DiskIndicator.vala Main.vala MainWindow.vala SettingsWindow.vala Utility/*.vala App/*.vala -o indicator-diskman --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg gio-unix-2.0 --pkg posix --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg gee-0.8 --pkg json-glib-1.0 --pkg libxml-2.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1
error: Package `gee-0.8' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `appindicator3-0.1' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
makefile:13: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/indicator-diskman_git/src'
makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

... which is weird, because I do have `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1` installed:

```
$ apt-show-versions -R appindicator3-0.1
gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1:amd64/bionic 12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1 uptodate
gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1:i386 not installed
gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1:amd64 not installed
gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1:i386 not installed
libappindicator3-0.1-cil:amd64 not installed
libappindicator3-0.1-cil:i386 not installed
libappindicator3-0.1-cil-dev:amd64 not installed
libappindicator3-0.1-cil-dev:i386 not installed
monodoc-appindicator3-0.1-manual:all not installed
```

I thought maybe I need to also install:

```
sudo apt install libappindicator3-0.1-cil  ## installs libappindicator3-0.1-cil libatk3.0-cil libcairo1.10-cil libgdk3.0-cil libgio3.0-cil libglib3.0-cil libgtk3.0-cil libpango3.0-cil
```

... but even with that in place, I still get `error: Package`appindicator3-0.1' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories` (which is probably not a surprise, since these -cil package seem to be related to the Mono language).

Could anyone guide me how can I get this extension built on 18.04?

Comment: There should be `gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1-dev` in repositories. Try with that.

Comment: Many thanks @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - unfortunately, it seems there is  [no such package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1-dev), so I get `E: Unable to locate package gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1-dev` when trying to install it. Any other suggestions?